# Offer/Answer vs IceCandidate

Tags: webrtc

I'm working on a webrtc project and trying to understand the difference between offer/answers and ice candidates.

In a [simple-peer example](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer#data-channels), two peers are able to connect without an offer/answer process. The "signal" exchanged between them is something along the lines of

```
{ candidate: 
     { candidate: 'candidate:...',
       sdpMLineIndex: 0,
       sdpMid: '0'
     }
}
```

which i believe is just an IceCandidate.

in Mozilla's [Simple RTCDataChannel Sample](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Simple_RTCDataChannel_sample), an offer/answer must be exchanged prior to generating an IceCandidate.

So I'm a little unclear about a few things:

1. What is the purpose of the IceCandidate, as compared to the offer/answer.
2. Can IceCandidates be created without an offer/answer process?
3. Can you connect to a peer simply knowing their IceCandidate?

Comment: Why do you think the simple-peer example can do without offer/answer? I would think the library abstracts that part, but it’s still there as part of the *signal*.

Comment: @deceze there's no cross communication between peer1 and peer2 in the simple-peer example prior to the `signal` event being fired

Comment: If there was, the library would be unusable since in production, the peers obviously won't be on the same machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@deceze ended up being right that simple-peer abstracts this out. The reason I misunderstood is that signal is not always the same object, and sometimes contains offer data.